# How to use the pyspark module in python script?

Tags: python, ide, apache-spark

I downloaded the pyspark module, and I would like to use it in my IDE (Spyder). But it is not working at all. I typed export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH  to include it in python path, but still "no module named pyspark" is the message I get.
Is it always that I have to use pyspark console in order to use the spark module? Is there no way to use the module directly in other python IDE?

Comment: Can you try setting the executable to call (preferences->console->advanced settings) from within spyder to be pyspark?

Comment: its not working neither

Answer (score 0):

First download sources from spark [website](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html). Then download and install sbt from this [website](http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html).Now go to sbt folder in spark source downloaded. Run sbt file with sbt package installed earlier. It will start building and will take around 30 minutes to complete.For more info,goto this [link](http://docs.sigmoidanalytics.com/index.php/How_to_build_SPARK_on_Windows).
Remember, you should have latest version of JDK installed in your PC/Laptop. Get JDK from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).After building , follow the commands given in spark website to create pyspark PYTHONPATH and environment. You can do this on spyder also.